# How can I properly set up a Gmail account in Apple Mail?

Tags: gmail, imap, apple-mail

I want there to be labels and not have 2 sent folders, etc. Also, ideally I'd like for the folders (or mailboxes) to not be all the way at the bottom, but rather right in the actual main mail area.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out mate http://db.tidbits.com/article/10253

Comment: Please don't post just a link. Please provide actual content to your answer, and also supply an extract of the link. If the link should ever stop working, this answer will be obsolete and useless.

Answer (score 1):

Apple's [Mail Setup Assistant](http://www.apple.com/support/macosx/mailassistant/) can walk you through it.  But for a gmail account, it looks like it is as easy as entering your email address and password into the new account dialog and clicking create - Mail apparently knows about gmail.